# assigining jsp variables to an array object in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Code:

```
<% String r="4";
   String b="5;
%>
<script>
  var a={"red":"<%=r%>","blue":"<%=b%>"};
</script>
```

Is it possible to do like this and how to  display those elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, You can use `hasOwnProperty` to get key and value.

```
<% String r="4";
   String b="5";
%>
<script>
  var a={"red":"<%=r%>","blue":"<%=b%>"};
  for (var k in a){
       if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          alert("Key is :" + k + ", value is :" + a[k]);
       }
  }
</script>
```

You can make it as JS object if you use `eval` function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you solve this problem.Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tuc1faug/1/  Here the values are displayed in the cells .I want these values to be hidden.And I want to store it inside the array.How to do it?

Comment: Yes always, Can you post this as a new question with your code and fiddle and what exactly you need.?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422413/hide-the-values-of-a-td-tag-using-jquery